# Profiling C++ code running on iOS device using instruments

Tags: c++, ios, profiling, instruments

I am trying to profile some signal processing code running on device using instruments. The code is written in C++. Below is the output ater profiling for a few seconds . . .

[image]

It is clear that the calls to powf are taking up the majority of the CPU time, however, I cannot find how to determine which calls to powf are the biggest offenders in my code. I swear that when I used to use shark, it was really easy to get line numbers for the calls in the source. All I can get from instruments is machine code nonsense.

Expanding the `powf` triangle gives the following . . . .

[image]

Comment: Click on the disclosure triangle next to powf to see the callers.

Comment: Just brings up a massive nested list of meaningless memory addresses

Comment: Sounds like you don't have symbols for at least some of your code (a library perhaps) ?

Comment: All my DSP code is written in plain old STL

Comment: Sure, but how are you building the code ? Is there a library ? Does the library have symbols or are you stripping it perhaps ?

Comment: It is all included in the project as raw source AFAIK

Comment: Could you add a screen dump with the powf disclosure triangle opened ?

Comment: Done. See edits. Thanks for looking

Comment: OK - it looks like some kind of callback - you're probably passing a function to something in CoreAudio. You might want to try profiling your code in a test harness where it gets called directly rather than via a callback.

Comment: Ah, OK. Yes, the heavyweight stuff is in a callback. Why does this prevent me from profiling properly? Is there a less time consuming method than harnessing?

Comment: You might be able to look up the caller addresses yourself using appropriate tools (nm or similar), but it's probably just as quick (and a lot more useful in the long run) to put together a simple test harness - you can even just profile on the Mac for a first approximation.

Comment: If you can provide a simple answer as to why I cannot get references to source code when using callbacks, I'll +1/Accept it :) Now to build a test harness.

Comment: Note - test harness version seems to be working

Comment: OK - have converted comments to an answer. Good luck with the profiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the code containing calls to `powf` is part of a callback function which you are passing to CoreAudio. Instruments seems to be unable to symbolicate the call chain for the callback, so you are just seeing raw addresses in the code. It *might* be possible to identify these addresses using a suitable tool (e.g. `otool`, or similar), but a better strategy in the long run would be to implement a test harness which calls your callback code in a loop with dummy data - this will most likely repay itself when you use it for future debugging and profiling activities. Note that for convenience you could just build the test harness as a Mac OS X executable for profiling/debugging, as bugs and performance bottlenecks will most likely be similar on both platforms, at least to a first approximation.